# Setting EC2 instance root device type to EBS in Rubber - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rubber

How do I set the `root_device_type` when creating an EC2 instance using `Rubber`?

I see that after creation of the instance, the serialized instance object has `root_device_type` as `instance-store`. I want to create an instance runs in an `EBS`.

They provide docs and sample config to create EBS volumes and mount it onto the instance but no documentation on how to create an EBS instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Phew! finally found how to change the configuration. Found this line the sample `rubber.yml`.

```
# REQUIRED: the ami and instance type for creating instances
# The Ubuntu images at http://alestic.com/ work well
# Ubuntu 12.04 Precise instance-store 64-bit: ami-eafa5883
#
# m1.small or m1.large or m1.xlarge
image_type: c1.medium
image_id: ami-eafa5883
```

Went over to `alestic.com`, got an AMI id for EBS Ubuntu 12.04 and thats it! :) (`ami-51821b6b`)

Would be nice if there was better documentation of this. Especially for people like me who are coming from DO and other hosts to EC2.